# Custom YouTube BBcode <object> doesn't allow to watch full screen

Tags: php, html, youtube, bbcode, vbulletin

I want to create custom BBCode for Youtube that will allow the user to open a full-screen video on my website. When I hover over a "full-screen" button it says:

> full screen is unavailable

I tried to add these attributes to my code: `frameborder="0" allowfullscreen`, and some other combinations, but to no avail.

```
 <object width="596" height="335">
     <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/WPni755-Krg">
     </param>
     <embed
         src="https://www.youtube.com/v/WPni755-Krg"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="596"
         height="335">
     </embed>
 </object>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? It will make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: @fin444 I posted the relevant code, can you please take a look

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the code you used to embed the video. Instead of using the [built-in embed feature](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en) from Youtube, you attempted to add it to the page as a `.swf` using `<object>`. This code should work properly:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WPni755-Krg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: If I can ask one more thing, I had try the same code with Twitch but It's doesn't work. '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel={playhearthstone}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

Comment: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed (why are you trying to embed the HCT?)